# How to check in ansible if a SHELL (/bin/sh) environment variable is defined

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I'd like to detect if a certain environment variable is defined. If it is defined then I'd like to carry a certain action otherwise carry out certain other action.

Question: How do I detect in ansible if a certain shell environment variable is defined?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want the current user:

```
- name: Get current user.
  set_fact:
    whoami: "{{ lookup('env','USER') }}"
```

That will not tell you whether the variable is defined.  If the variable is not defined in the environment, your `set_fact` variable will be empty.  If you want to use some default if the variable is not set...

```
- name: See if environment variable MYVAR is set
  shell: "env | grep '^MYVAR='"
  failed_when: 1 == 0
  register: result

- name: Get MYVAR or use 'DEFAULT'
  set_fact:
    myvar: "{% if result.rc == 0 %}{{ lookup('env','MYVAR') }}{% else %}DEFAULT{% endif %}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a read up on [Ansible Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html) and checkout:

```
- debug:
    var: ansible_env
```

And therefore for conditional stuff, you can do things like:

```
- set_fact:
    env_var: <SOME ENV VAR TO CHECK FOR>
- debug:
    msg: "ENV {{ env_var }} is {{ ansible_env[env_var] is defined | ternary('defined', 'not defined') }}"
```

which results in:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ENV USER is defined"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ENV USR is not defined"
}
```

For `env_var` set to 'USER & 'USR'.

Bear in mind that parts of the env will look different, dependent on which user you are connected to the remote host as.